# Merge Rows with same index in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to transform this:

| Index | col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BTU26 | UF |  |
| BTU26 |  | 1400 |

To this:

| Index | col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BTU26 | UF | 1400 |

*Note that there are strings and int

Comment: `df.groupby('Index').first()`.

Comment: didnt work on the large one

Comment: Correction, it did work on the entire Data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.